# Is there an efficient way to turn a multi-dimensional dictionary into a list in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to teach a neural network how to play Noughts and Crosses in Keras, but am having problems with my efficiency. I have done some timing and found that this line is taking up 80% of the time:

```
value, logits = neural_net.predict(numpy.array([game.make_image()]))
```

There are two possible reasons this is running slowly:

1. The predict function is taking ages.
2. The game.make_image() function is very inefficient.

As I have no control over the speed of Keras's predict function, I decided to have a look at the make_image function, which takes the game's board (represented by one bitboard for each player in a 3D dictionary, for efficiency reasons), orients it according to the current player and adds a 3x3 board representing which player it is, while turning it into a list so that it can be input to the network.

Here is the code:

```
def make_image(self):
    return [[[self.board[self.to_play][key][key2] for key2 in self.board[self.to_play][key]]
             for key in self.board[self.to_play]],
            [[self.board[1 - self.to_play][key][key2] for key2 in self.board[1 - self.to_play][key]]
             for key in self.board[1 - self.to_play]],
            [[self.to_play for key2 in self.board[0][key]] for key in self.board[0]]]
```

Is there any way I can make this more efficient, or is the time being taken mostly by the predict function?

Note: the to_play variable is either 0 or 1, with 0 being the first player to play and 1 being the second.

EDIT:
Example board as would normally be played:

```
O|X|
 |O|X
X|O|X
```

Representation of this board in the dictionary:

```
{
 0: {0: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
     1: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1},
     2: {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1}}

 1: {0: {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0},
     1: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
     2: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0}}
 }
```

Wanted representation in the array:

```
[
 [[0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1]],

 [[1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0]],

 [[0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0]]
]
```

Comment: post sample input and expected output. also remove unnecessary details from post

Comment: I don't think you gain significant time difference using "3x3 dict" or "3x3 list", but the transform should be easy

Comment: This will give you the list representation:   [[list(y.values()) for y in x.values()] for x in dict.values()]

Comment: @LevB sorry I should have mentioned. I tried that and it took about 10% longer

Comment: @Jan Stransky, I am looping through this so many times that even a small difference can end up causing an improvement of several hours overall

Comment: @Arkleseisure sorry, the question is a bit long with many not so relevant details, hinding the core of the question. What is actually your goal? :-) Try to make `make_image` function as efficient as possible? Or the looping on the result of `make_image` as fast as possible? Something else?

Comment: My goal is to make the make_image function as efgicient as possible